# connect to oracle9i using python2.7 on ubuntu 64bit

Tags: python, ubuntu, oracle9i

OS: Ubuntu 13.10 64bit
Python : 2.7.5
Oracle Database : Oracle 9i (remote)

how to connect to oracle using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to connect to Oracle successfully using the [cx_Oracle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.1.2) module. (CentOs 5.9, Python 2.7.5, Oracle 10)

The code would be something similar to:

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid)
db = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, dsn)
```

After connecting to Oracle, you can create a Cursor object to make queries.